# Is there a tool to view entity relations from a sql script?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql file with a long list of create tables and alter tables. Is there a tool available to look at the entity relationships that result from running the sql script. It would be great to not have to start up a local database to perform this. I am running macOS Mojave v10.14.5. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try QueryScope and see if it works for you. You can try it online [here](https://app.sqldep.com/queryscope/demo/)
It should be able to analyze fairly complex SQL queries. You can just copy and paste the query you want to analyze